# JSON Parser with jquery.TokenInput (format)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a problem with jquery.tokenInput.

This is my tokenInput code:

```
$(".search-betrocket").tokenInput("http://www.websitehere.com/web/search", {

    searchDelay: 2000,
    minChars: 3,
    tokenLimit: 5,
    hintText: "Buscador inteligente...",
    noResultsText: "Sin resultados",
    searchingText: "Buscando...",
    theme: "facebook",
    queryParam: "txt",
    propertyToSearch: "NickName",

    resultsFormatter: function(item){ return "<li>" + "<img src='" + Users.Avatar + "' title='" + item.first_name + " " + item.last_name + "' height='25px' width='25px' />" + "<div style='display: inline-block; padding-left: 10px;'><div class='full_name'>" + item.first_name + " " + item.last_name + "</div><div class='email'>" + item.email + "</div></div></li>" },

    tokenFormatter: function(item) { return "<li><p>" + item.first_name + " <b style='color: red'>" + item.last_name + "</b></p></li>" }
});
```

The problem is de parser...
jquery not know much as to understand the json parser returned objects.

**This is my code JSON result _GET request**

```
{
    Users: [
        {
            Id: 264,
            NickName: "SirBet",
            Avatar: "19b452bf3fe83e17de82b67e518361d2",
            Ranking: 3233,
            FirstName: "Sir",
            LastName: "Bettor",
            Gender: "H",
            Location: "Valencia",
            Description: "Acepto todo tipo de retos :)",
            CountryId: 1,
            Country: "EspaÃ±a",
            CountryISO: "ES",
            PrivacyUpdated: 0
        }
    ]
}
```

What is not is how to navigate the json object to function properly. 
Ie enter via **$val['Users']['0']['Nickname']** format but jquery / json.

Does anyone help me?

Comment: What error do you get? Also, is that a direct copy of the JSON output from your website? If so, it is invalid. JSON requires keynames be wrapped in double-quotues: `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if ur json is...

```
[{Id:1, NickName:xxxx, Avatar: "19b452bf3fe83e17de82b67e518361d2", Ranking: 3233}]
```

then..

```
$.each(data, function(a, b) {

    alert (b.Id);
    alert (b.NickName);
    alert (b.Avatar);
    alert (b.Ranking);

});
```

Comment: Mmmmmm sorry JAAulde this is not my JSON this is de problem, i dont know parser this json in jquery format. THIS IS MY JSON

{
    Users: [
        {
            Id: 264,
            NickName: "SirBet",
            Avatar: "19b452bf3fe83e17de82b67e518361d2",
            Ranking: 3233,
            FirstName: "Sir",
            LastName: "Bettor",
            Gender: "H",
            Location: "Valencia",
            Description: "Acepto todo tipo de retos :)",
            CountryId: 1,
            Country: "EspaÃ±a",
            CountryISO: "ES",
            PrivacyUpdated: 0
        }
    ]
}